# How do you run pytest tests on functionality inside of a for loop and yield?

Tags: pytest, python-3.7

For example,
I pass a list of data into a function. How do I pytest on **get_message**, **foo_function**, and **yield**?

I figure I can pytest on the **foo_function** on it's own but struggling to find examples of how I would test an iterative function generally and one that uses yield specifically.

```
def get_message(records):
    for record in records:
        data = foo_function(record)
        if data['message'] == 'BAR':
            yield {
                'result': 'OK',
                'message': data['message']
            }
```

Comment: You can just convert the result to a list (e.g. `list(get_message(records))`) and test against the resulting list. Depending on the complexity of `foo_function` you also may want to mock that.

Comment: Did you had time to look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70340534/4413446)? It would be nice to have your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example providing some hints.

- `yield` output is a generator, the `next` method with a default value (`None` in this case) can be used to retrieve and test the value.
- `pytest.mark.parametrize` can be used to test different combinations
- In the example I have written a dumb `foo_function` to return some test data. According to your use case you can choose to mock it.

```py
import pytest


def foo_function(record):
    data = {"OK": {"message": "BAR"}, "NOK": {"message": "FOO"}}
    return data.get(record)


def get_message(records):
    for record in records:
        data = foo_function(record)
        if data["message"] == "BAR":
            yield {"result": "OK", "message": data["message"]}


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "record,result", [("OK", {"result": "OK", "message": "BAR"}), ("NOK", None)]
)
def test_get_message(record, result):
    assert next(get_message([record]), None) == result
```

Test execution

```sh
pytest -rA test_mock.py
# ...
# PASSED test_mock.py::test_get_message[OK-result0]
# PASSED test_mock.py::test_get_message[NOK-None]
```